# On Excel I want to create a list from another sheet based on two values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 2 values in dropdown menus in cells B2(DATE) and B5(ITEM).

from these values I want to create a list of items(based on B5) that were sold on that date(B2).

The transactions are listed on a different sheet (TRANSACTIONS) by 
Date (D4:D503); Item (E4:E503); Qty (I4:I503).

By looking around on various forums I have been able to look up values based upon the date(B2) but can't work out how to refine it further (I don't fully understand how what I have now fully works)

```
=INDEX(TRANSACTIONS!$D$1:$K$503,SMALL(IF(TRANSACTIONS!$D$1:$K$503=$B$2,ROW(TRANSACTIONS!$D$1:$K$503)),ROW(1:1))*1,2))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a list, how? Print it? Put it in another drop down?

Comment: In a block of cells I want to create a list

Comment: Why not use a pivot table?

Comment: Have never used pivot tables so have absolutely no idea how to set them up - based on your comment I did try to set one up but the "Wizard" was of no help. This is my first use of "Index" normally use "Vlookup".

Comment: Well if you want to return an array of values you'll need to select the array of cells when you put in your formula. I'd look more into pivot tables and mess around with that to see if it can do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, thanks for your advice.
I have managed to get the sheet to show what I want using dropdown lists, filters and arrays.
Not as Automated as I would of liked but it does show what I need it to.